# Applying vector based clustering algorithms to social network context

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

i have a social network described as edges in a file. I used graph based clustering algorithms to find dense parts of the graph. However there is also vector based clustering which i need to apply to the data i have, but i can not find any context to this. I have also information about each node considering their features. I think using vectors containing the features of each user makes no sense here. For example k-Means would calculate the distance between user u1 with his feature vector v1 = [f1,f2,f3,..] and user u2 with its feature vector v2 = [f1,f2,f3,...]. However both vectors would have binary values depending on which feature the user has. Additionally i have a matrix with the users on one axis and the features on the other, where the user is able to set permission.

My Question is now, how i can make use of k-means, dbscan etc. in the context of this topic.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Many algorithms can be modified to allow being used with distances for binary features. For example k-means can be modified for binary data: k-modes.

But I don't think it will do anything useful on your data.

You approach to this problem is bad: **don't first decide the algorithm**, then try to make it run. You are then bound to solve the wrong problem. Instead, **formalize the problem first**, in mathematics, what a good clustering would be. Then identify the appropriate algorithm by it's mathematical ability to find a good solution to this objective.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I am in the middle of my work when i realized that the algorithms do not fit to my data. Didn't now about that and i don't want to remove a big amount of pages. Therefore i try to find a way to make use of them in my context. In this paper they used k-means however and said that it classifys or groups objects based on
attributes or features into k number of group, which is exactly what i also want to do. But i do not understand their methadology: http://interscience.in/IJCCT_Vol3Iss3/paper20.pdf

Comment: Forget these Indian journals. Just ignore them. Use more reliable sources.